# Modulating Code for c++

Tags: c++, parameters, module

I have heard that it is best practice to 'modulate' your code, to minimize the amount your code relies on other sections of your code.

If I have a `float`:

```
float X = 1000;
```

And a function that uses `X`:

```
void A()
{
    //use X
}
```

Is it better practice for the function to directly use `X`, or to use a passed parameter like this:

```
void A(float param)
{
    //use param
}
```

And call it like this:

```
A(X);
```

Or simplify use the first function?

Comment: This is called dependency injection, you may find some docs over it explaining the merits and demerits.

Comment: Iv'e done some reading on this. I can see the obvious benefits in the way of testing. What would be some downsides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is bad:

```
// Define global variable ...
float X = 1000;
// ... and expect A() to work with it ...
A();
// ... because there is a hidden dependency.
```

This example is good:

```
// Define local variable ...
float X = 1000;
// ... and let A() work with it.
A(X);
// Everything is explicit and clean here.
```

Please note that the *good approach* allows you to simplify the code in this way:

```
// Just do it.
A(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best rule of thumb for deciding if something should be a parameter or a global is simply "will you ever call it with a different argument"? That is, will `A` ever need different values for `X`?

If `X` is a constant, like the number of bits in a byte or the gravitational constant, make it a constant and don't waste time passing it in as a parameter. If, on the other hand, it is something that might vary from call to call, then please make it a parameter.

Also, don't modularize needlessly. If you only ever use `A` in one place, and `A` isn't particularly long, then you might be better off putting it in-line - it will reduce the amount of code that someone has to read to understand your code.

Comment: Well the thing is, will A ever use values different to X? Maybe. Not at the moment, but in my code I am trying to work more with paramiters than direcly accessing global variables becuase I never know what I will do in the future of the code and want to make it the most dynamic and re usable code I cam

Comment: Be careful. There's a balance to be struck between planning for the future and implementing what you need today. Too much genericity without a corresponding immediate need can lead to unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring `X` globally only for the function `A()`, well you shouldn't.
Rather declared it locally in main and pass it in a function through the parameter.

Also, If you are declaring `X` just for the function and want to modify it's value, you should pass it by reference.

```
void main ()
{
    float X = 1000;
    A(&X)
}

void A(float *ptr)
{
    // Do operations with *ptr which has the value of X in main()
}
```